# Crashed while using NSKeyedArchiver

Tags: iphone, ios6, game-center, nskeyedarchiver

I have a NSMutableArray and NSString I want to Archive these and also want to retrieve array and string with out change data inside the array and string.

I given like this,

for Archive,

```
NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
                        NSKeyedArchiver *archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData:data];
                        [archiver encodeObject:arrayRandomNumberForUser forKey:@"array"];
                        [archiver encodeObject:stringBingo forKey:@"string"];
                        [archiver finishEncoding];
```

for UnArchive,

```
NSData *data=match.matchData;
    NSKeyedUnarchiver *unarchiver = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:data];
    mutableArray = [unarchiver decodeObjectForKey:@"array"];
    stringtakenValue = [unarchiver decodeObjectForKey:@"string"];
    [unarchiver finishDecoding];
```

Where, match.matchData is an NSData object getting from **gamecenter** take turn method.

When called the take turnMethod it is crashed. Here is the Console window error message.

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: ' **-[NSXPCEncoder encodeObject:forKey:]: This coder only encodes objects that adopt NSSecureCoding (object is of class 'NSKeyedArchiver').'**

Answer (score 0):

I not sure but I think unarchiver returns an NSArray, not an NSMutableArray. So try

```
mutableArray = [[unarchiver decodeObjectForKey:@"array"] mutableCopy];
```